# Append a div as a parent of an ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have this html.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
 <div class="dataTables_paginate">
  <!-- some content here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Having this, i want to append a new div at the top of `dataTables_paginate` so the new html will look like this.

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <div class="ui menu pagination">
     <div class="dataTables_paginate">
       <!-- some content here -->
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If i try with

```
$('.dataTables_paginate').parent().append('<div class="ui pagination menu"></div>')
```

This append the div but dosnt wrapp `dataTables_paginate div` inside the new appended div.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function for this. try this code:-

```
$('.dataTables_paginate').wrap('<div class="ui pagination menu"/>');
```

Answer (score 2):

As you just want to add a new parent use `wrap()`:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate').wrap('<div class="ui pagination menu"/>');
```

jQuery will close any element compiled by it so you can do this:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate').wrap('<div class="ui pagination menu">');
```

or even this:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate').wrap($('<div>', {"class": "ui pagination menu"}));
```

That last version is useful if you want to apply multiple attributes to the new element.

Answer (score 2):

Use the jquery `wrap` function.

```
$('.dataTables_paginate').wrap('<div class="ui menu pagination" > </div>');
```

Comment: Note: You can either *self-close* the `div`, or forget about closing it at all with jQuery.